# Removing all events in 'ext:CalendarPanel'

Tags: c#, calendar, ext.net

Is there any possibility to remove all event items from an **ext.net** (C#) calendar ?

```xml
<ext:CalendarPanel ID="CalendarPanel1" runat="server" Region="Center">
  <CalendarStore ID="CalendarStore1" runat="server">
    <Calendars>
      <ext:CalendarModel CalendarId="1" Title="Home" />
    </Calendars>
  </CalendarStore>
  <MonthView runat="server" ShowHeader="true" ShowWeekLinks="true" 
      ShowWeekNumbers="true" />  
    <Listeners>         
      <DayClick Fn="CompanyX.ShowDiagClickDay" Scope="CompanyX" />
    </Listeners>
  </MonthView>
</ext:CalendarPanel>
```

I tried this code, but with no result:

```
this.CalendarPanel1.CalendarStore.RemoveAll();
this.CalendarPanel1.CalendarStore.Sync();
```

Answer (score 3):

solution Using JavaScript :

```
CompanyX.getStore().removeAll();
```

CompanyX is the namespace used :D

Using ASP.NET

```
CalendarPanel1.CalendarStore.RemoveAll();
CalendarPanel1.Render();
```